# How do I write the following JQuery functions in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to build a configurator with transparent images. Right now the image configurator works over a simple JQuery function: I have given each input element a data attribute which I have called data-Image. The function catches the data-Image of a selected option and loads it on a inline style of an element.

```
<div id="configurator-image"></div>

<select id="configurator">
    <option data-image="url(http://test.com/img/option1.png)">option1</option>
    <option data-image="url(http://test.com/img/option2.png)">option2</option>
</select>
```

```js
$("#configurator").change(function(){
    $("#configurator-image").css("background-image", ($('#configurator option:selected').data("image")));
}).change();
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPaGVM

I'm trying to figure out the best practice. Background images and seperate elements, that are waiting for being used may not. 
Would it be smarter to simple create a img for a selected option, and
how does such a function look like?

I want to reduce web site load and may not use JQuery when it's possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about refactoring working code, so belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: It would be smarter to use `'http://test.com/img/'+$('#configurator').val()+'.png'`

Comment: Have you tried writing it without jQuery? Should be fairly simply with basic [DOM features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: `configurator.onchange=function(){window["configurator-image"].style.backgroundImage= configurator.value;};configurator.onchange();`, changing data-image to value

Comment: The question is too broad. It's asking if a different approach should be taken to a problem and asking how to reimplement *multiple* jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function config() {
  document.querySelector("#configurator-image").style.backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#configurator option:checked').dataset.image;
}
config();
```

```css
#configurator-image {
  height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="configurator-image"></div>

<select id="configurator" onchange="config()">
  <option data-image="url(http://cardstock-test.de/products/feinleinen/agenda/chamois-inside.png)">option1</option>
  <option data-image="url(http://cardstock-test.de/products/feinleinen/agenda/schwarz-inside.png)">option2</option>
</select>
```

Does this work for you? You may use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).